# Disadvantages/dangers of promiscuous mode

Tags: linux, networking, ip, multicast, promiscuous-mode

The only way I am able to receive multicast UDP datagrams on a building automation module is by setting the interface to promiscuous mode (kernel is 2.6.24, it works as it should on later kernels). I would like to know if there would be any risks or disadvantages if i deliver them this way to the customers, as each packet would be forwarded to the kernel without prior filtering